# [ROS2] [launch_pytest] node outputting to stderr instead of stdout

Tags: ros, ros2, roslaunch, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As asked by @clalancette, I am reposting [launch issue #619](https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/619) here.

- Operating System:

  - Ubuntu 20.04.4
- ROS2 Distro:
- foxy
- Version or commit hash:

  - launch: 1.1.0
  - (launch_ros: 0.20.0)
  - (pytest: 7.1.2)
- DDS implementation:

  - rmw_cyclonedds_cpp
- Client library (if applicable):

  - rclpy

#### Steps to reproduce issue

copy-paste the following in `test_confusing.py`, then run `pytest test_confusing.py`

```
import launch
import launch_pytest
import launch_ros
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def foo_node_process() -> launch.actions.ExecuteProcess:
  return launch_ros.actions.Node(
      package='examples_rclpy_minimal_client', executable='client', name='client', output='screen', cached_output=True
  )

@launch_pytest.fixture
def foo_launch_description(foo_node_process) -> launch.LaunchDescription:
  return launch.LaunchDescription([foo_node_process])

@pytest.mark.launch(fixture=foo_launch_description)
def test_read_foo_stdout(foo_node_process, launch_context):
  assert launch_pytest.tools.wait_for_start_sync(launch_context, foo_node_process, timeout=5)

  def validate_output(output: str):
    assert len(output) > 0, 'Output is empty'

  # passes
  launch_pytest.tools.assert_stderr_sync(launch_context, foo_node_process, validate_output, timeout=5)
  # fails
  launch_pytest.tools.assert_output_sync(launch_context, foo_node_process, validate_output, timeout=5)
```

#### Expected behavior

The output of the launched node (logging info messages `"service not available, waiting again..."`) should be in `stdout`.

#### Actual behavior

The output is in `stderr`, causing a confusing fail of the test.

#### Additional information

I am a bit confused by the `output='screen'` argument and the fact that the [`pytest_hello_world.py`](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/074cd2903ddccd61bce8f40a0f58da0b7c200481/launch_pytest/test/launch_pytest/examples/pytest_hello_world.py) is using `assert_output_sync`. However, it is maybe intended behavior, as running `ros2 run examples_rclpy_minimal_client client` also outputs to `stderr`.
Is it normal? Could you help me understand?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402368/%5Bros2%5D-%5Blaunch_pytest%5D-node-outputting-to-stderr-instead-of-stdout/) by [LoicF](https://answers.ros.org/users/108268/loicf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short, it is by design that all output from `RCLCPP_{DEBUG,INFO,WARN,ERROR,FATAL}` macros (and their equivalent `logger.{debug,info,warn,error,fatal}` in rclpy) goes to stderr.

Back in Dashing and Eloquent, we used to output DEBUG and INFO messages to stdout, and all of the other ones to stderr.  However, this caused confusion and made it hard to handle log messages at every level since you would have to capture both stdout and stderr.

Between Eloquent and Foxy, I did some pretty exhaustive research into the logging systems in languages like Python, Ruby, Rust, etc. (see https://github.com/ros2/rcutils/pull/181#issuecomment-546553594).  What I found out was that all logging systems pick a single stream and log to that.  Most of them log to stdout by default, but some log to stderr by default.  We decided to log everything to stderr, to keep stdout available for use by the application.

I'll point out that this is configurable; if you set the environment variable `RCUTILS_LOGGING_USE_STDOUT` to `1`, it will use stdout by default.

---

Originally posted by [clalancette](https://answers.ros.org/users/30031/clalancette/) with karma: 256 on 2022-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1